# Does delegatecall pass up the events?

Tags: solidity

I want to use delegatecall in one function to populate an event from the contract I'm calling. Here's a minimal example:

```
contract Caller {
    address public callee;

    function Caller(address _callee) {
        callee = _callee;
    }

    function delegate() {
        callee.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("call()")));
    }
}

contract Callee {
    function call() {
        Log(msg.sender);
    }
    event Log(address sender);
  }
```

However, the receipt I get in my truffle contracts return an empty array for the logs. Does delegatecall not push the log into the receipt?

I want to be able to "return" a value from the delegatecall.

Answer (score 0):

Your Callee contract is declaring the event but you have to emit it.

```
contract Callee {

    event Log(address sender);
    
    function call() {
       emit Log(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Also note that a contract cannot listen to another contract event. So you will have to listen to Callee events from the front end.

Comment: Are you sure about the last part? I would think that since delegateCall was used, the event would be logged with the Caller contract as emitter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a contract cannot listen for another contract events. Because even if it was, it wouldn't be able to return anything from a view call or perform any action that require gas. So it wouldn't do nothing.

Comment: Yes, a contract cannot listen to an event. What I meant is that you wrote that he has to listen to Callee events from the front end. I think that he has to listen to Caller events instead, since delegateCall would make the event belong to the Caller, not the Callee.

Comment: Well if he want's to listen for an event in the Caller then the event should be emitted from the Caller when ever a delegate call happens.